# Issue with bootstrap 4 in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, requirejs

I am having issue while loading bootstrap 4 in magento 2

```
var config = {
 paths: {
    'popper': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min',
    'bootstrap': 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min'
},
shim: {
    'popper': {
        'deps': ['jquery'],
        'exports': 'Popper'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        'deps': ['jquery', 'popper']
    }
}
 };
```

- I have create `requirejs-config.js` as above code.
- When I load the page it gives me an error

> GET http://localhost/project/popper.js net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost/project/popper.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.
>
> Uncaught Error: Script error for: popper.js
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>       at makeError (require.js:166)
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Comment: I face almost same issue, hope any genius will take interest in this and post answers

Comment: Hello I solved the issue, and added bootstrap 4 ,  using bootstrap.bundle.js